# Why emails are sent to spam after migrating my website from one server to another server

Tags: email, spam, live-migration

Emails sent from my website worked normally & were sent to the Inbox correctly. But now I made couple of below changes & the emails were now in SPAM.

I have actually 2 servers. One is for Pre-Prod & Another is Live.

Changes I made are,
1. Changed 'From Email' address in both Pre-Prod & Live. This email is active.
2. Migrated my Live website from old server to new server.

If I send out emails from my Live website, the emails are now in SPAM but it is all fine if I send out emails from Pre-Prod website.

Please help to let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Could it be related to [Sender Policy Framework](http://www.openspf.org/Introduction) i.e. have you remembered to update your `example.com. TXT "v=spf1 ...` to include the IP of your current server?

Comment: @EsaJokinen, Not sure about that. I will let our IT team to take care of this point. Thanks

Comment: With only this information, your question is really broad. You should at least provide example headers of a message that was detected as SPAM. Although reading through it probably already tells you what's wrong.

Comment: @EsaJokinen, I thought it would be straight forward for IT guys. I will check with our IT team & update the question if needed

Comment: Checking the headers of the emails that are getting marked as spam might also help, and if it doesn't, you could consider updating your question to include both headers for mail marked as spam, and for mail that is not.